# What does *display mean in CSS?

Tags: cross-browser, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a star-preceded property mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css)

I came across this while browsing for cross-browser support for display: inline-block...

```
selector {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

What does *display do?

Link from:
http://www.aarongloege.com/blog/web-development/css/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: I doubt -moz-inline-box is necessary, Gecko supports inline-block now.  zoom: 1 is also likely unnecessary, as display: inline-block; accomplishes the same task.  For IE6 just having an ordinary *-less display: inline; last will take precedence, and for other IE's you can probably have it in another rule afterwards still without the * and it will work the same.  (Basically, this blog post always had silly code, and it's only more silly at this time than it was.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
*property: value;
```

**This is a hack, so I don't recommend that you use it**. Styles represented like this are interpreted only by IE 7 and below, so other browsers ignore those styles completely.

It's non-standard (or valid) CSS, but it's sometimes used to beat IE into submission.

Answer (score 6):

as other have said this is a hack for IE7 and below

**BUT** this one, the example you've given is a specific hack so unlike a comment you've received I wouldn't recommend removing  it yet.. you can move it or remove it after you read this and don't need it ;)

btw I agree -moz-inline-box is probably no longer necessary, it was for older versions of Firefox

```
selector {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

Is a specific hack to get IE6/7 to display a **block level element** as an inline-block.  Although IE has supported `inline-block` since v5.5 it didn't do so natively on block-level elements

So in this case what you need to do is give the element "layout" (`zoom: 1;`) and feed it `display: inline` after that.

Now `display:inline-block` also gives an element layout so if you remove the `display-inline` rule to a separate ruleset (either in a conditional or a hacked rule) you no longer have to use `zoom: 1;`

My preferred hack for this (for demonstration purposes) & because inline-blocks are so dashed useful, & because it's shorter is

```
selector {
  display: inline-block;
}


selector {
  display: inline !ie7;
}
```

that `!ie7` is doing the same as the `*` before the display property, it's feeding that rule to IE7 and below - you could use the `*` version in the second rule too, however the !ie7 makes it clear, to me anyway it's a hack, and who it's for.

If you have a specific, conditional style sheet for IE7 and below you can simply put the second rule  in it - without any `*` or `ie7` ;)

```
selector {
  display: inline;
}
```

because IE will still read the first ruleset and get it's hasLayout triggered to `true` by the `inline-block` in there, you don't need `zoom`

the quoted hack you mention is popular because it keeps all the parts in the one ruleset, but `zoom:1` is needed in that case as `inline-block` won't work to set hasLayout if it's in the same ruleset as the other `display` property

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in front is a hack for IE browsers, specifically versions and 7 and below.  You may also see `_display` as well, where `_` in front is a hack for IE versions 6 and below.  CSS Rules with those will only apply to the those versions, and ignore by other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack for IE 7. That property will be applied to IE 7 only.

I always refer to [Comprehensive List of Browser-Specific CSS Hacks by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing to the other questions:

CSS specification says that any property not recognized should be discarded. This is due to future compatibility.

So, for most browsers, `*property`, is not a valid property, and they'll just skip.

IE7, for reasons I don't know, recognizes `*property` as `property`, and them process it, while others won't.