# CSS validation error

Tags: css

When I tried to validate my website on CSS [Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) it shows errors at universal selector "*" Parse error. Can somebody help on this? I used the twitter bootstraps css.
like following code

```
.row-fluid .span12 {
  width: 99.99999998999999%;
  *width: 99.94680850063828%;
}
.row-fluid .span11 {
  width: 91.489361693%;
  *width: 91.4361702036383%;
}
.row-fluid .span10 {
  width: 82.97872339599999%;
  *width: 82.92553190663828%;
}
.row-fluid .span9 {
  width: 74.468085099%;
  *width: 74.4148936096383%;
}
.row-fluid .span8 {
  width: 65.95744680199999%;
  *width: 65.90425531263828%;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your CSS or we have a hard time helping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a star-preceded property mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses the (in)famous [Star Html Hack](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Star_Html_Hack), which means using *intentionally* broken CSS code in order to deal with IE 6. Just ignore the error messages.

Comment: It should be added that the star hack also works for IE7, when using a star in front of your *property*, but when using a star in front of a *selector* it only works for IE6. [Read more here](http://www.republicof3.com/a-few-cross-browser-css-hacks-every-developer-should-know/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi now remove `*` of `width`

now if you are using `IE` than create a saparate `CSS` file  and link to your document

**as like this**

```
Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target everything EXCEPT IE

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->

Target IE 7 ONLY

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->

Target IE 6 ONLY

<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 5 ONLY

<!--[if IE 5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 5.5 ONLY

<!--[if IE 5.5000]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie55.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 6 and LOWER

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 7 and LOWER

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 8 and LOWER

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 6 and HIGHER

<!--[if gt IE 5.5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 7 and HIGHER

<!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

Target IE 8 and HIGHER

<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```