# What does *zoom:1 do in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have noticed in bootstrap responsive CSS, there is this class:

```
.row{margin-left:-30px;*zoom:1}
```

I've never come across an inline `*` inside a css property. Could anyone clarify what this does?

Comment: It's a hack for IE7.  Only IE7 accepts css properties with an * at the start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a star-preceded property mean in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css)

Comment: I did my home work but i guess i didnt search the right query :) thank u for notifying me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's like an inline conditional statement for IE5.5 - IE7. Only IE 5.5, IE6, and IE7 will display `zoom: 1` because of the inline `*` (known as the "star property hack"). Similar to the IE6 hack with the underscore `_`.

See: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/targetting_ie7

Comment: Thank you :) never had a chance to come across this before :)

Comment: To be more specific, `zoom: 1` gives the element 'layout', which is just one of those magical things in the IE rendering engine that makes it so special. http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: It's not IE7 only. IE6 and maybe IE5 also interpret properties prefixed with an asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the **[star property hack](http://kid666.com/2006/07/05/33/)** *(aka the Holly Hack)* and is similar to the [underscore hack](http://wellstyled.com/css-underscore-hack.html).

It's used to set a property for the IE (v5-v7) family only.