# What is "*" in *margin-left in css

Tags: css

This is the first time i'm going to encounter this I've scrape a website and extracted all the styles and one thing that caught my eye is this code like so:

```
   ul.tabs { 
      position: absolute; 
      margin-top: 480px; 
      width:100%; 
      background: URL("../design/images/masters/bkng-tabs-navigation.png") no-repeat 50% 17px; 
      height: 70px;  
      *margin-left: -487px; /* What is "*" in here */
   }
```

What is the meaning of **'*'** in `*margin-left` because when I removed it, it doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css

Comment: Oh pardon for that I just didn't use `asterisk` keyword when I tried to search. You can close this thread tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's called the [star hack](https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=494). It's a way of resetting a CSS attribute for only IE7 or below, because these browsers have a bug that let them ignore the star and apply the attribute named after the star. Other browsers will see `*[attribute name]` and consider it malformed or unknown, and ignore it.

In your case, it will only apply `margin-left: -487px;` on IE7 or below; other browsers/versions of IE will ignore that.

This is generally considered poor form or a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Why is that when I removed the asterisk it doesn't work?