# Asterisk at the end of CSS property

Tags: css, yui

What is the Asterisk at the end of CSS property (font and font-family)?

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2009, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved.
Code licensed under the BSD License:
http://developer.yahoo.net/yui/license.txt
version: 2.8.0r4
*/
body{
    font:14px Minion New,times,clean,serif;*
    font-size:small;*
    font:x-small;
    }
pre,code,kbd,samp,tt{
        font-family:monospace;*
        font-size:108%;
        line-height:100%;
    }
```

Is it the same as [the IE7 hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css)? But This asterisk is at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a star-preceded property mean in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css)

Comment: I know that IE hack. But this asterisk is at the END, while the one you mentioned is at the beginning.

Comment: You can see it if you eliminate the whitespace between rules - because whitespace in CSS has no effect on how it's read by the browser, an asterisk at the end of a line can be considered at the start of the subsequent line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a css hack, used for IE8 the properties with the asterisk in front only affect in the navigator IE8.

In the end or in the begining is the same for css.