# How to not inherit universal selector (*) in css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this class in my css file

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;}
```

It looks like this class * puts every thing at margin 0 and padding 0. This class overwriten bootstrap OL and UL list.

How do I not inherit that * class for my OL and UL list from Bootstrap?

This is what the * does to my OL and UL listing. Unindented
[image]

Comment: Can you include your HTML and `OL` `UL` CSS? In general `*{}` only specifies default styles but any styles you apply to classes assigned to `ul` `ol` should no be overwritten.

Comment: My code is simple like this `<ol>
 <li>41ft-128ft 4-sect. full power megaform boom</li>
 <li>4-sheave main boom nose</li>
 <li>Aux. single sheave boom nose</li>
</ol>

<p>LMI/A2B pat datalogger LMI light bar</p>

<p>Compu-Crane selection</p>

<ul>
 <li>LMI Calib. for 2 x 20ft lattice inserts</li>
 <li>33ft-56ft manual offset bi-fold swingaway</li>
 <li>HP30-19G grooved drum main &amp; aux. hoists</li>
</ul>
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` pseudo selector.

```css
*:not(ul):not(ol) {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<p>paragraph</p>
<h1>heading</h1>
<ul>
  <li>ul</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>ol</li>
</ol>
```

You could also introduce a class that specifies your padding/margin, and use that on elements you want to apply it to.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

.pad {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<p>paragraph</p>
<h1>heading</h1>
<ul class="pad">
  <li>ul</li>
</ul>
<ol class="pad">
  <li>ol</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If I do like this, does it affect other areas that needs to use * class? Some other areas in my page still need to use * for OL and UL.

Comment: @delphiman \* applies to every element on the page. If you make a change to \*, it affects all elements. If you selectively want to modify the padding or margin for *certain* elements, use a specific class that overrides the stuff in \*. I gave an example like that in my answer with the `.pad` class

Answer (score 0):

somewhere below the * {}, just re-add the styles you removed

.my-list { padding: 10px; }

There is no real good reason to use * to begin with. If you want a global reset, just chain the elements together that you want reset and apply to those.

other discussions about this:
[What does a star-preceded property mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css)